# iOS & Android: swap from paid app to free with in-app billing/purchase

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm about to develop my first paid app for Android and iOS (both native). My plan is to release the first version just for purchase (no free). Later on I want to swap it to free with two levels of in app purchases.

My issue/question is: How can I make sure when a user of the first payed version of the app gets the in-app pruchase content when he/she updates to the new (free with in-app billing) version?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950895/in-app-billing-get-if-the-user-purchased-the-app-before-it-was-free) 15 month old post with kinda the same question...

Maybe something has changed since then - and it doesn't help with iOS. Thats why I put this question up.

Thanks a lot for your input
Soko

Comment: I would advise against this model because you are just making life difficult for yourself. You can create a setting in NSUserDefaults with your first version and check for this in later versions to automatically unlock the in-app features, but if the user uninstalls and reinstalls the app for some reason then this value will be lost. Also if the user installs the app on an additional device they will not get the free unlock

Comment: Thanks. So the better way is to do v1 already as a free app with in-app billing... Are there other options that might work but get me out of the hassle dealing with in-app purchases in v1?